# create a matrix of 691 rows and 1 column Matlab

Tags: matlab, date

I want to create in Matlab a matrix of size `691x1`, but every row to be incremented by 100. For example:

ans :

```
0
100
200
300
400
500
600
700
.
.
691(time)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `:` operator as:

```
mat = (0:100:690*100).';
```

You can read more about the colon operator in [here](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html#f1-85242).

Comment: You know, sometimes the world is complex.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of desired elements in the vector, you may also consider using [`linspace`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html):

```
mat = linspace(0, 690*100, 691 ).';
```